# How to generate URL with specified query param in .NET Core router?

Tags: c#, .net, pagination, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following route config

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/@page={page}",
        new {page = 1}
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

And I need URL like `http://<domain>/customers?page=1` 
But @URL helper gives me empty string. Here is the code of usage this helper

```
<h1>@Url.Action("Customers", new {page = 1})</h1>
```

`Customers` method for this controller:

```
public IActionResult Customers(int page = 1)
{
    var customers = _customerRepository.Customers;

    var onePageCustomer = customers.ToPagedList(page, 25);  
    ViewBag.onePageCustomer = onePageCustomer;            
    return View(onePageCustomer);
}
```

Please help me to understand how it works on the example from my question.

#### Update

I have tried this

```
<h1>
    @Url.Action("Customers", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        {"page", 111}
    })
</h1>
```

but it gives me empty string too.

#### Update 2

As @Kirk Larkin sad me in comment I update my code. And it's almost works. Here is the new code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/pageNumber={pageNumber}",
    new {page = 1}
);
```

And helper call:

```
@Url.Action("Customers", "Home", new {pageNumber = 123})
```

But it gives me URL with strange % symbol and without query param like: `/Home/Customers/pageNumber%3D2`

How to avoid this? I need just `/Home/Customers?pageNumber=2`.

#### Update 3

Actually I have the following settings:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/@page={page}",
    new {page = 1}
);
```

And view

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList) ViewBag.onePageCustomer,
    page =>  Url.Action("Customers", new {page}),
    new PagedListRenderOptions
    {
        LiElementClasses = new string[] {"page-item"},
        PageClasses = new string[] {"page-link"}
    })
```

As you can understand this is pagination. I'm trying to use this package [link_on_github](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some research and with the help of comments under the question I have understood how it works.

**First.** I need only one `RoteMap`. It's

```
`routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`
```

Default as you can see. You can use `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();`. This call will generate absolutely the same code. See about this in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#setting-up-routing-middleware)

**Second.** I have to use `pageNumber` instead of `page`. Or something different. Because of `page` is reserved word. I have been a few confused because of documentation of `pagedList` that I use. This tells use exactly `page`. See [pagedList](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList)

I hope it will helpful for somebody who has fighting with pagination in .Net like I had.